# write a python running process on disk

Tags: python, linux, fedora

I accidentally delete my python script but after I started running it so I have PID and other related information about the process.
my question is, is it possible to find a way to save it on disk while it is still running?
I am on Fedora 27.

Comment: Try : `lsof -p {pid}` which will give you a list of open files from the given pid - there might be a script or file hanging around somewhere

Comment: Thank you for your fast intervention. I see alot of so files, socket open(network) but no hanging script